Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition Sign In Issue: Script Error 'addEventListener' not supported
I just installed Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. However, I am facing problem to sign in. The error I got is:
Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
I tried to report this issue from the Visual Studio but the send feedback would need me to sign in first, hence couldn't proceed. Even the VS Community web site is asking to report via Visual Studio.
Has someone else encountered this problem and managed to get sign in?
Edit:
The url that triggered the error is:
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?scope=openid+profile+email+offline_access&response_type=code&client_id=51483342-085c-4d86-bf88-cf50c7252078&response_mode=form_post&display
Final Edit:
On 25th May 2024, the server side script had been fixed and I finally can sign in. The sign in process had some glitches though, where I was prompted multiple times to key in password again and again with passcode sent to alternative email. I ended up using passcode sent to my mobile phone and had to enter 2 times (sent passcode to my mobile phone 2 times separately) in order to finally get signed in.

Are you getting the error during sign in on the Microsoft login popup which shows the regular Microsoft Azure Entra B2C login page. As far as I can tell only IE version <= 8 don't have support for this.

I am not sure if it is the regular Microsoft Azure Entra B2C. The url that's reported in the error message box is:
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?scope=openid+profile+email+offline_access&response_type=code&client_id=51483342-085c-4d86-bf88-cf50c7252078&response_mode=form_post&display

Ok, I'm glad I'm not the only one seeing this today. I am getting this in SSMS and in VS 2022 when trying to log in via Microsoft login.

The fix is currently being made server side.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-wont-let-me-log-in-/10663175#T-ND10665696

Keeping my finger crossed, the fix not yet happened. Hopefully tomorrow or so it will be fixed. I shall update the post if I can get in later. Thanks.

On 25th May 2024, the server side script had been fixed and I finally can sign in. The sign in process had some glitches though, where I was prompted multiple times to key in password again and again with passcode sent to alternative email. I ended up using passcode sent to my mobile phone and had to enter 2 times (sent passcode to my mobile phone 2 times separately) in order to finally get signed in.

I'm also having the same problem. I worked around this issue by changing the embedded web browser to the system web browser from Options -> Environment ⇒ Account.

It worked in my environment too! Thank you very much.

I checked VS 2017, unfortunately the option to select embeded web does not appear. I think this only applies to VS 2022.

@user25185685 is there a reason you can't upgrade to VS 2022 Community Edition

Account options is on the sign in window.
It looks like you can fix it by also changing to system web browser and then back to Embedded web browser.options dialog

I checked VS 2017, unfortunately the option to select embeded web does not appear. I think this only applies to VS 2022.

This solution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/work-with-multi-factor-authentication?view=vs-2022#enabling-system-web-browser
Only works for VS2022. All other versions continued to be broken. This is acknowledged by MS:
https://vsstatus.visualstudio.com/
-=tg=-

Hmm... bad news. I checked VS 2017, unfortunately the option to select embeded web does not appear. I think this only applies to VS 2022. Seems to be inline with the link https://vsstatus.visualstudio.com/ that you posted.
I hope Microsoft can solve this soon, cause I have tons of VS 2017 projects and won't like to migrate to VS 2022.
